# How to use localization custom message in expo location permissions

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I want to set location permission message in two languages English and French. How i do it ?

```
[
    "expo-location",
    {
      "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use your location."
    }
  ]
```